# Tutorial slim test $app->get(x) error

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

After doing the following [Tutorial](https://www.codecourse.com/library/lessons/php-authentication-system/setting-up) (9:48) about Slim and testing a Slim function I still receive a "Page not found".

The Programm is supposed to echo any word typed in the search bar after a certain point eg.If searched for "http://localhost/authentication/public/test/Hello", the page should echo 'Hello', the page should **echo 'Hello'**.

This is done by using a .htaccess file to re-route any link to index.php. The index.php file then runs the php file which is called start.php.

Any suggestion for why this might not be working?

**Slim v3.x**

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php

require '../app/start.php';

$app->run();
?>
```

start.php

```
<?php 

use Slim\App;

session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

define('INC_ROOT', dirname(__DIR__));

require INC_ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App();

$app->get('/test/:name', function($name) {
echo "Hello! {$name}";
});
?>
```

Comment: Do you use Apache web server? Where are .htaccess and index.php located in the directory structure? On what URL do you directly access your index.php, is it http://localhost/authentication/public/index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to use Slim 2 Code while using Slim 3.
You have to change your code to the new structure or switch back to v2.

There is an example like yours on the [slimframework homepage](http://www.slimframework.com/):

```php
//example taken from slimframework.com
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```

I'd recommend read through the [official docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/).

Comment: As an aside, I've been using Slim 3 for about 4 months and it's an absolute pleasure. It gives you a starting point and you can make your app as complex or keep it as simple, tied only to the most basic pattern of modern web development